# remove bug report option from file picker - File Picker Intent - android

Tags: android, android-intent, filepicker

I have created Intent to choose any file like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
```

After that i have added below lines to select local file only and remove irrelevant app like Drive etc

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
}
```

After that i have added below lines for single file selection

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, false);
}
```

After that i have added below line to remove irrelevant app like Contacts or any other

```
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
```

At last

```
context.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_ANY_FILE);
```

**Problem 1:** Still default File Picker in android is shows "Bug Report" option, how can i remove that option. (Tested in Nexus 5x - android 7)

**Problem 2:** File Picker shows Hidden files, how can i enable or disable hidden files so that it's selection can be enabled or disabled (Tested in Nexus 5x - android 7)

Comment: "I have created Intent to choose any file" -- that `Intent` does not choose a file. It allows the user to choose a piece of content, from available `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`-supporting activities. If you want to choose a file, and you want to control the presentation to the level that you seek, add [a file-chooser library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/35) to your app.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare,
I doesn't wants to implement any library. I gives priority to default android system functionality.
Can you tell me how can i create intent so that any local file can be selected like txt, html, xml, apk, pdf, audio, video any local files.
Somethings i doesn't want to be selected like contacts, Bug reports, or any other irrelevant files.

Comment: "Can you tell me how can i create intent so that any local file can be selected like txt, html, xml, apk, pdf, audio, video any local files" -- there is no such `Intent`. Android focuses on content coming from arbitrary locations, not files on the filesystem. Either use a library, create your own file-browsing UI, do not limit yourself to files (and accept the other features of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`), or eliminate this feature from your app.

Comment: Thanks, If user select Bug Report file than i getting path in onActivityResult() like this "content://com.android.shell.documents/document/bugreport%3Adumpstate_log-2016-09-21-08-06-57-4461.txt".  How can i convert it to File object.

Comment: You don't. Nothing returned by `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` has to be a file. You will notice that the action name is not `ACTION_GET_FILE`. If you get a `Uri`, like the ones delivered to `onActivityResult()`, [consume the content from the `Uri` properly](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html) (e.g., `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) the right answer is,
There is no such Intent. Android focuses on content coming from arbitrary locations, not files on the filesystem. Either use a library, create your own file-browsing UI.